# How to Expose local server to the web

Tags: json, webserver, sensors, localserver

Need helps ! I've retrieved the sensor data from my Raspberry pi via RestAPI , but it is running in a local server. I'd like to expose this to the web. I've tried NGROG, localTunnel but it's not working the way I want. Are there any other alternatives I can try to archieve this ? .  Thank you.

[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp2Lx.png)

Comment: Do you want to expose it out to the whole web or just your local home network?

Comment: I want it expose to the whole web, so that someone outside of my network can also access it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set up port forwarding on your router to forward port 5000. How this is done will depend on the model of your router. You should be able to find documentation online by searching for your router model.